# Sticky session and ssl passthrough

Tags: ssl, load-balancing, haproxy

I'm working with HAProxy 1.5.18 where I would like to keep the passthrough configuration for SSL requests but I would like to enable the sticky-session. This is an extract of my config and the problem with it is that the cookie is not set and I don't have any error trace.

Does someone have any idea on what the problem could be? It should be possible to set the cookie without SSL termination isn't it?

global

```
global
    log         127.0.0.1 local2 info
    chroot      /var/lib/haproxy
    pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid

    #Enable/Disable server
    stats socket /var/run/haproxy.sock mode 600 level admin
    stats timeout 2m

    user        haproxy
    group       haproxy

    daemon
```

defaults

```
defaults
    mode               http
    log                global

    #get HTTP request log
    option             httplog

    #timeout if backends do not reply
    timeout connect    10s

    #timeout on client side
    timeout client     60s

    #timeout on server side
    timeout server     60s

    #enable stats
    listen  stats   *:8888
    mode            http
    log             global

    stats enable
    stats hide-version
    stats refresh 30s
    stats show-node
    stats admin if TRUE
    stats auth admin:*****
    stats uri  /stats
```

frontend HAProxy_Frontend

```
frontend HAProxy_Frontend

    # listen multiple ports
    bind *:80
    bind *:443
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
    mode tcp
    option httplog

    default_backend    HAProxy_Backend_default
```

backend HAProxy_Backend_otcs

```
backend HAProxy_Backend_otcs

    # balance with roundrobin
    mode               tcp
    balance            leastconn
    cookie SERVER insert indirect nocache
    http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
    http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Proto http if !{ ssl_fc }

    # health-check on URL implementation
    option httpchk GET /context/ping
    option log-health-checks
    http-check expect string true

    # define backend servers
    server             SRV0009 xx.xxx.x.xxx:443 check check-ssl verify none cookie SRV0009 backup
    server             SRV0010 xx.xxx.x.xxx:443 check check-ssl verify none cookie SRV0010
    server             SRV0012 xx.xxx.x.xxx:443 check check-ssl verify none cookie SRV0012

    errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errorfiles/503.html
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It should be possible to set the cookie without SSL termination isn't
> it?

No, it should not! Without SSL termination you are talking about man in the middle attack on encrypted data. Cookie is HTTP header and as such is a part of encrypted payload.
In your config you use `mode tcp`, so you can attempt stickiness based on TCP values, like IP or IP+port or switch to `mode http` and SSL termination and then modify HTTP headers as much as you like, including stickiness based on cookies.

P.S. 1.5.18 was released at 2016-05-10, maybe it's time to update it :)

Comment: Thank you for clarification @tbielaszewski, it totally makes sense (also to evaluate an update :) ).